# How to pass the data to save it in an url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html

I need a code for this using webservice.

Post url is http://172.25.183.183:8080/jiraservice/rest/create/ and post parameters are
 Summary
Desc
Type
Acc_cr

Explanation:
Desc:"As a"+whoTextField.text +"\n I want"+whatTextView.text+"\n so that"+outputTextField.text

Type:"story"

Comment: If you are passing parameters in the URL you should use GET rather than POST. Then you can simply add a query string at the end of your URL. Here's a good article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Another method without sending parameters in URL, you can use [RESTClient](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) to call the endpoint of your service and send the parameters in request body in form of the object your service consumes.